# Vue not running in FireFox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Version
2.5.11

Reproduction link
https://jsfiddle.net/ranjs/eh10wju7/

Steps to reproduce:

In Google Chrome this works fine but in Firefox I get the error:

> 'TypeError: undefined is not a constructor[Learn More]

and nothing is displayed on the screen.

```
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor[Learn More] build.js:1:182494
<anonymous>
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:182494
<anonymous>
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:181955
r
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:96
<anonymous>
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:4377
r
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:96
<anonymous>
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:247068
r
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:96
<anonymous>
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:457
<anonymous>
http://localhost:25555/static/dist/build.js:1:2
What is expected?
App shows normaly
```

What is actually happening? Getting the error and nothing is displayed.

I upload my `main.js` and this is my `package.json`:

```
'{
  "name": "chatbotmariana",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Ranieri Abreu Silva Junior <rabreu@indracompany.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --port 80  --hot --host 0.0.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "express-minify": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.3"
  }
}
```

I'm using JavaScript and I dont have `tsconfig`.

.bablrc :

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {    
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css'
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "file"
      },{
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]   //  <=  Order is very important
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work fine in my Chrome. Stuff like `import Vue from 'vue'` needs to be run through something like Babel (using Webpack; I see both are in your package.json, but your fiddle isn't using the Webpack/Babeled code) before most browsers can understand it.

Comment: Also on Google Chrome, also not working for me either.

Comment: This is just a piace of my code, I add the .babelrc config

Comment: my app is hosted is https://marianabot.hmg.infraticampos.com.br/

Comment: In development mode check your app in firefox (that way you can see the compiled code before it's minimized) and post what you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found.

```
const SpeechRecognition =
    window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  recognition.lang = "pt-BR";
  recognition.interimResults = false;
  recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
```

This code don't works in firefox